# Python - Font Displays All Square

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, fonts

I have a file that converts a text into an image.

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
from PIL import ImageFont

from random import seed
from random import randint

'''Returns the text size in terms of width and height.'''
def getSize(txt, font):
    testImg = Image.new('RGB', (1, 1))
    testDraw = ImageDraw.Draw(testImg)
    return testDraw.textsize(txt, font)

text = "As fast as thou shalt wane so fast thou grow'st,
In one of thine, from that which thou departest,
And that fresh blood which youngly thou bestow'st,
Thou mayst call thine, when thou from youth convertest,
Herein lives wisdom, beauty, and increase,
Without this folly, age, and cold decay,
If all were minded so, the times should cease,
And threescore year would make the world away:
Let those whom nature hath not made for store,
Harsh, featureless, and rude, barrenly perish:
Look whom she best endowed, she gave thee more;
Which bounteous gift thou shouldst in bounty cherish:
She carved thee for her seal, and meant thereby,
Thou shouldst print more, not let that copy die."

fontname = "MSGEOTX1.TTF" # Times New Roman Special G1 Font
fontsize = randint(10,50)  
colorText = "black"
colorOutline = "white"
colorBackground = "white"


font = ImageFont.truetype(fontname, fontsize)     
width, height = getSize(text, font)    
img = Image.new('RGB', (width+4, height+4), colorBackground)
d = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
d.text((0, 0), text, fill=colorText, font=font)
d.rectangle((0, 0, width+3, height+3), outline=colorOutline)

img.save( "image.png")
```

But when the image is rendered it shows all square boxes. Why is it?

[image]

Comment: Totally unrelated, but in Python comments are done using the `#` symbol, not triple-quoted string litterals.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers We can add a multiline string (triple quotes) in our code, and place our comments inside it.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers --> https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_comments.asp

Comment: I didn't say using strings (however they are quoted FWIW) was technically illegal, I said that those were NOT comments. Unless used as [docstrings](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html?highlight=docstring), it's considered bad coding style to use litteral strings as comments.

Answer (score 3):

This might be cause the font is 'currupted' basically the font doesn't have those characters. Since the font cant render what it doesn't have it display squares, there might be a problem with your font.
Try to change to another font, or try another method to display it.

Comment: other font is working, but I wanted this specific font to be working.

Comment: If other fonts are working with the exact same code, then the problem is the font you're targeting, not the code itself.

Comment: Since other fonts is working there is _definitely_ something wrong with this spesific font. But if you really want this font, I would try to get the font from another website.

Comment: The font is missing glyphs for these characters. Most commonly used fonts have wide range of glyphs that cover common scripts (latin, greek, hebrew, cyrillic, arabic, etc). The font is not "corrupted", it just does not cover the script.